# How to make vertical span in android table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have 3 rows and 3 columns, I want to place image in the (1,1) place, and span it vertically to hold the vertical place, can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_span="3" to span 3 columns. For example:

```
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/item_id"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="item text" />     
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: this for horizontal span, I need vertical span